# Ext.data.Store created with no model

Tags: extjs, proxy, store, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

After upgrading my custom proxy from ExtJs 4.1.0 to 4.2.*, stores broke in our application.  I'm getting the warning below.  Note, I say "warning" and not "error".  I don't see anything rendered in my page, so I'm not sure if this is the only thing that broke.

**JavaScript Warning:**

```
Ext.data.Store created with no model.
```

**JavaScript Warning screen shot:**

[image]

**Call Stack with Detail:**

... the line in the JavaScript Warning for ext-all-dev.js is 12300, but the actual line in the code below is 10974.

... see `con[level](message);`

... level = "warn"

[image]

**ExtJs Store:**

```
var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    proxy: Ext.create('Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy', {
        url: '/Myapp/WebServices/SharedService.asmx/GetDropdownOptions',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        extraParams: {
            user_login: 'MacGyver',
            table_name: '[user]'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            model: 'DropdownOption',
            root: 'd'
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
    }),
    autoLoad: true
});
```

**Custom Proxy:**

[image]

Comment: Stores need to define models or fields.

Comment: well, that eliminated the warning.. the store still isn't pulling any data, so it sounds like the upgrade on the framework caused some other serious issues

Comment: Why r u using a custom proxy? i don't see anything that would require a custom class.

Comment: No good reason.. it's all I found on the internet.  If you have a simpler way of implementing an ExtJs ajax proxy and asmx web services, let me know.  Right now, the class in my asmx web service and the model have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the model config to the store fixed this warning, but I was dealing with a bunch of new issues from the ExtJS 4.1.0 to 4.2.1 upgrade, so it was difficult to figure out what went wrong.  I took a different route since then.  I'm now implementing the extdirect4dotnet server-side stack for the standard Sencha Ext.Direct proxy.  The off the shelf code for this framework was for .NET 3.5, so I'm in the process of upgrading it to .NET 4.0 and then upgrading the JavaScript code from ExtJS 3.0.0 to 4.2.1.  I'm 1/2 way there, so crossing my fingers.